# LO/LC, CSO/CSC Valve Definition

Tags: mechanical-engineering, valves, standards

Does any one here know of an authoritative source (ASME, ISA, NFPA, OSHA, etc..) that gives a definition for the following in one of their standards or codes and the number for that standard or code:

- LO (Valve Locked Open)
- LC (valve Locked Closed)
- CSO (Valve Car Sealed Open)
- CSC (Valve Car Sealed Closed)

I'm not looking for an explanation, I'm looking for a citable code.

Answer (score 2):

That would be Process Industry Practices, Practice Ref. PIC001. Issued 7/15/1998.
Appendix A1 contains exactly what you listed.

Edit: I just came across this online: [PIC001 Sample, Not for Commercial Use](http://www.cheme.utm.my/staff/arshad/images/lecture/mkh1223/pid_sample.pdf)

Comment: I agree that PIC001 contains exactly what I listed, however I am looking for definitions, not what the abbreviations stand for.  Thanks for looking though.